# align the image on the right

Tags: html, sass

I need to align the following image to the left as the example that I only leave that I do not understand because it always leaves me a margin of the sides.

[image: tm]

my code:
Html:

```
   <section class="container7">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center w-75 p-3 w-responsive">
        <h1 class="h1-responsive font-weight-bold text-center my-5">Descarga nuestra app móvil</h1>

            <p class="text-justify w-responsive mx-auto mb-5">
                Descarga nuestra app y ten el servicio ¡Al alcance de tus manos!
            </p>
            <div class="row store text-center">
                <img width="30%" class="google d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center img-responsive " src="assets/images/google.png" />
                <img width="30%" class="apple d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center img-responsive" src="assets/images/apple.png" />
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
                <img width="75%" class="phone img-responsive" src="assets/images/phone.png" />
        </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

scss

```
.container7 {
    margin: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #632878 9%, #862453 56%, #a83a39 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;

    .phone{
     float: right; 
     margin-right: 0px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

}
```

ERROR

[image]

Comment: Check your CSS code `.container7` is close wrong way, `.phone` must be outside last `}`

Comment: What margins are you talking about?

Comment: What do your classes w-75 p-3 w-responsive look like? Also check if .container7 has no padding.

Comment: @NirajKaushal maybe it's just SCSS or some other CSS-preprocessor

Comment: Not quite sure what margins you are referring to. Are you using Bootstrap? If so, do not modify the base class such as `.container` as it will affect margins.

Comment: @CristianTraìna yeah it may be possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things:
First, as Niraj already said, the container 7 must be closed before the phone bracket opens.
But second, you need to add something into your code:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

.container7 {
    margin: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #632878 9%, #862453 56%, #a83a39 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}

.phone{
     float: right; 
     margin-right: 0px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7v0xryLa/), there is no white or black border (or how you call it: margin) on the sides.

Edit: As it's SCSS, here's a valid SCSS script which works:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;

    .container7 {
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #632878 9%, #862453 56%, #a83a39 100%);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        position: relative;

        .phone{
             float: right; 
             margin-right: 0px;
             margin-bottom: 0px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP's using SCSS though, `css` is fine

Comment: @IvanS95yes,  bad mine in the description

Comment: @IvanS95 does not work does not line up to the left leaves a margin always. Check my publication place the error capture

Comment: @Vision The margin occurs as you have forgotten to add the first part of my CSS If you add this, the mistake you describe as the margin on the left will disappear. I've created a new jsfiddle with SCSS where it works, look here as a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ev3c0h49/

Comment: @Korne127 continues taking the margin, that is, it does not work

Comment: @Vision Ok, that's weird…
Have you looked at https://jsfiddle.net/ev3c0h49 ?
There is no margin as you describe it, but if you remove `box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;`, then the margin you describe is there. So, I think it has likely to do with this issue…

Comment: @Korne127 If I've seen what happened to me! I am using mdboostrap. Something must be causing me conflict in my styles

Comment: @Vision Is there any update? I am asking as the problem, as you described it, disappears in the fiddle. Do you know what caused the error?

Comment: @Korne127  I have not kept trying that part, I'm moving to see if with the freshest mind I can see the solution